# Snowflake where date between two column statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello dumb question having issues running where Value between two fields of a record search appears to not work as intended e.g

```
Select * from table where '2022-03-31' between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE
```

Comment: Please add sample table data.

Comment: Looks good to me. What data type is `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE`. I suspect it's not `DATE`.

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem. Is it throwing an error? Output vs expected output

Answer (score 0):

As we do not know the exact data types I suggest to explicitly cast literal and colums to DATE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE '2022-03-31'::DATE between FROM_DATE::DATE and TO_DATE::DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

[BETWEEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/between.html) is start and end range inclusive

```
WITH table_of_data(from_date, to_date, note) as (
    SELECT 
        to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
        to_date(column2, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
        column3
    FROM VALUES
        ('2021-03-01', '2021-05-01', 'wrong year'),
        ('2022-03-31', '2022-04-01', 'first day'),
        ('2022-03-01', '2022-03-31', 'last day'),
        ('2022-03-01', '2022-05-01', 'in the middle')
)
Select * 
from table_of_data
where '2022-03-31' between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;
```

gives, as expected (by me):

| FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | NOTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-31 | 2022-04-01 | first day |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 | last day |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-05-01 | in the middle |

casting the string to a date is more correct, but the SQL parser will auto do this, but that works also:

```
Select * 
from table_of_data
where '2022-03-31'::date between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;
```